# Las distancias entre mis letras varían al renderizarse en los navegadores

Tags: html, css, interfaz-gráfica

Necesito que con una fuente `monospace` la distancia entre mis letras sea constante de tal forma que las letras mostradas en el ejemplo sean siempre vistas en conjunto como un cuadrado y no como un rectángulo.

```css
#cuadrado {
  background: none;
  position: fixed;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 7px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="cuadrado">
  <pre>
AAAAA
AAAAA
AAAAA
AAAAA
AAAAA
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Alguna razón es especial para necesitar este comportamiento?

Comment: Quiero que se mantenga para formar algunas geometrías con las letras @jasilva

Comment: Monospace significa que el ancho de los caracteres es constante entre ellos, no quiere decir que sea igual al alto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Igualando Line Height al font size con fuentes Mono funciona.

```css
#cuadrado {
  background: none;
  position: fixed;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 7px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  
  
  line-height:7px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cuadrado">
  <pre>
AAAAA
AAAAA
AAAAA
AAAAA
AAAAA
</pre>
</div>
```